# SQL Query or Table Error?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

So Im trying to find the total amount spent on Cuts and Products by each Customer

I don't know if my Query is Wrong or my entire Database Schema any ideas?

**My Query**

```
`Select First_Name, SUM(B.Cost), SUM(C.Cost)
FROM bookings A, cuts B, products C, customers D
Where A.Customer_ID= D.Customer_ID
AND A.Cut_ID = B.Cut_ID
AND A.Product_ID= C.Product_ID;`
```

**My Database**

```
`Table: bookings 
Booking_N0, Customer_ID, Cut_ID, Product_ID, TimeTaken`


`Table: customers
Customre_ID, First_Name, Sex`


`Table: products
Product_ID, Products, Cost`

`Table: cuts
 Cut_ID, Cut, Cost`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `GROUP BY` to `SUM` by each customer :

```
Select D.First_Name
     , SUM(B.Cost)
     , SUM(C.Cost)
FROM bookings A LEFT JOIN cuts B ON A.Cut_ID = B.Cut_ID
                JOIN products C ON A.Product_ID = C.Product_ID
                JOIN customers D ON A.Customer_ID = D.Customer_ID
GROUP BY D.First_Name;
```

Also, look forward using *explicit join notation* (`FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field2`) instead of *implicit join notation* (`FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field2`), because it is has more intuitive view (tables are listed near conditions on which they are joined).

Comment: Adding the group by statement seems to fix it however i have stumbled upon another problem, When a customer just buys a product (cuts is NULL) it doesn't add it onto the total sum.

So the sum is only when all the columns are not NULL

Comment: @Tzhari : You can use `LEFT JOIN` to list values that are in `bookings` but missing in `cuts` (values will be `null` for `cuts` columns).

Answer (score 0):

Start using recommended `JOIN / ON` syntax for joining instead of using `WHERE` clause . You also need a `GROUP BY` clause

```
Select First_Name, SUM(B.Cost), SUM(C.Cost)
FROM bookings A
INNER JOIN cuts B
 ON A.Cut_ID = B.Cut_ID
INNER JOIN products C 
 ON A.Product_ID= C.Product_ID
INNER JOIN customers D
 ON  A.Customer_ID= D.Customer_ID
GROUP BY First_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use aggregate function like SUM you have to add a group by clause
in your case:

```
 ...
 AND A.Product_ID= C.Product_ID
 GROUP BY First_Name
```